# Can't keep the array order with orderBy in ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I'm totally stucked with this issue.

I've got an array returned in a specific order from the server and I display items through a `ngRepeat`.

I would like to keep the same order as the array's order at the beginning but I can't. It automatically sorts my array by Id.

```
ng-repeat="item in filtered = (items | orderBy:predicate:reverse)"
```

When this is loaded, I really need to keep the same order than the array returned from the server.

What is wrong here ?

Comment: Why do you use `orderBy` if you don't want to sort the elements, but keep them in the original order? Just use `item in items`.

Comment: No. I don't want to sort them at the beginning. The user is able to change that thanks to a selector.

Comment: Set the predicate to null if you don't want to sort, and use `item in filtered = (predicate == null ? items : (items | orderBy:predicate:reverse))`

Comment: Thank you ! I really didn't think about ternary here.